# SQL Sum two values within same query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Good Day,

I have a table that contains 3 columns. Date, Store, Straight_Sales. Each day a new record is created for each store with their previous day's sales.

What I am trying to do is generate a result set that has both current month to date sales for each location as well as the past year same MTD sales.

I can accomplish this by using two totally separate queries and result sets however I am trying to include these in the same query for reporting purposes.

Here are my two current queries that work just fine:

Last Year Month to Date:

```
     SELECT SUM(summ_sales_daily.straight_sales), store_master.name 
     FROM
     store_master 
     INNER JOIN summ_sales_daily ON store_master.unit = summ_sales_daily.store 
      WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW())
     GROUP BY summ_sales_daily.store ORDER BY summ_sales_daily.store
```

Current Year Month to Date:

```
     SELECT SUM(summ_sales_daily.straight_sales), store_master.name 
     FROM
     store_master 
     INNER JOIN summ_sales_daily ON store_master.unit = summ_sales_daily.store 
     WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW()) 
     GROUP BY summ_sales_daily.store ORDER BY summ_sales_daily.store
```

I'd like these to return the current and previous years MTD in the same result along with the store name (hence the join)

Any help would be awesome!

Using MariaDB

Comment: Should there be a `WHERE` clause in your first query?

Comment: try something like this ,
SUM( case When YEAR(date)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) Then summ_sales_daily.straight_sales else 0 End)  MTD,
SUM( case When YEAR(date)=YEAR(NOW()) Then summ_sales_daily.straight_sales else 0 End) YMTD

Comment: Yes sorry. When I copied and pasted I had to manually format it to look correct. Somehow deleted that. Fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of the MariaDB syntax, but see if you can use the case statements as I mentioned. Remove the where clause for Year, just keep it for Month

Comment: union might solve your problem.

Comment: I think he needs two different columns in same resultset. You can union, but then you will have to pivot the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use conditional aggregation and move the different conditions into a case expression within the sum function:

```
SELECT 
    store_master.name
    , SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) THEN summ_sales_daily.straight_sales ELSE 0 END) last_year_sales
    , SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(date)=YEAR(NOW()) THEN summ_sales_daily.straight_sales ELSE 0 END) current_year_sales
FROM store_master 
INNER JOIN summ_sales_daily ON store_master.unit = summ_sales_daily.store 
WHERE MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW())
GROUP BY summ_sales_daily.store 
ORDER BY summ_sales_daily.store;
```

Or you can calculate the two different values in a couple of derived tables that you join with:

```
SELECT 
  store_master.name, 
  last_year.sales as previous_mtd, 
  current_year.sales as current_mtd
FROM store_master 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT store, SUM(straight_sales) sales
    FROM summ_sales_daily
    WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW())
    GROUP BY store 
) last_year ON store_master.unit = last_year.store 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT store, SUM(summ_sales_daily.straight_sales) sales
    FROM summ_sales_daily 
    WHERE YEAR(date)=YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(date)=MONTH(NOW()) 
    GROUP BY store 
) current_year ON store_master.unit = current_year.store ;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f72a8/2)

The first solution would probably perform better.